# How do I save my fine tuned bert for sequence classification model tokenizer and config?

Tags: model, save, bert-language-model

I want to save all the trained model after finetuning like this in folder:

```
config.json
added_token.json
special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer_config.json
vocab.txt
pytorch_model.bin
```

I could only save pytorch_model.bin but other details I could not reach to save, How I could save all the config, tokenizer and etc of my model?

I used

```
tokenizer.save_pretrained('results/tokenizer/')
```

but earror apears

```
AttributeError: 'BertTokenizer' object has no attribute 'save_pretrained'
```

I saved the binary model file by the following code

```
torch.save(model_to_save.state_dict(), output_model_file)
```

but when I used it to save tokenizer or config file I could not do it because I dnot know what file extension should I save tokenizer and I could not reach cofig file,
Is there any way to save all the details of my model?
thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you defined the tokenizer and what you assigned the "tokenizer" variable to, but this can be a solution to your problem:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(...)
tokenizer.save_pretrained('results/')
```

This saves everything about the tokenizer. And to save the model settings as well, run:

```py
[... your fine-tuning code]
your_model.save_pretrained('results/')
```

Saved files in the output are:

> config.json
> added_token.json
> special_tokens_map.json
> tokenizer_config.json
> vocab.txt pytorch_model.bin

**UPDATE following the comment:**

If you are using `from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertForSequenceClassification` then that attribute is not available (as you can see from the [code](https://github.com/maknotavailable/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/blob/master/pytorch_pretrained_bert/modeling.py#L814)).

What you should do is use [transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) which also integrate this functionality.

Example:

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model.save_pretrained('results/tokenizer/')
```

Another solution would be to use [AutoClasses](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/auto.html#automodelforsequenceclassification).

Comment: I tried your code your_model.save_pretrained('results/tokenizer/') but this error appears torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'BertForSequenceClassification' object has no attribute 'save_pretrained'

Comment: Yes of course, now I try to update my answer making it more complete to explain better

Comment: I tried your updated solution but error appears torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'BertForSequenceClassification' object has no attribute 'save_pretrained'

Comment: You are not using the code from my updated answer. You are continuing to use ```pytorch_pretrained_bert``` instead ```transformers```. Please copy and paste my last three lines and you will see it works.

Comment: given that I fine-tuned the model and I want to save the finetuned version not the imported version and I could save the .bin file of my model using this code model_to_save = model.module if hasattr(model, 'module') else model  # Only save the model it-self
    output_model_file = os.path.join(args.output_dir, "pytorch_model_task.bin") but i could not save other config files

Comment: more clearly I retrieve ber for sequence classification model ('bert-base-uncased'), then train it on my own data 'model.train()', the resulting model is called 'model' now I want to save the resultiong model, tokenizer, config, vocab and all other json files of my trained model not bert for sequence classification

Comment: I used     xmodel = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model)
without calling transfromer because my code deals with pytorch and this error apprears torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'BertForSequenceClassification' object has no attribute 'decode'